# Angular Proxy redirecting POST requests to GET

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I need to do POST requests to a external API, but every POST request I try to do the proxy are changing to a GET request without headers. What I did wrong in proxy configuration?
Proxy code:

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = {
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://qa-2-api-workflow.runteccorp.com",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "followRedirects": false,
    "httpVerbOverride": false,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": "/api/",
    }
  }
}
}; module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

Http Call

```
auth(user : string, password : string){
    return this.http.post( //http = HttpClient
      "/api/login",
      { email: btoa(user), password: btoa(password)},
      { observer: "response" }
    ).
    pipe(tap(res => {
        const authToken = res.body['access_token'];
        this.setToken(authToken);
    }));

}
```

The browser behavior with proxy (route expecting a POST, not a GET):
[image]

Comment: Please provide your http call in your service also

Comment: @IdontwearString I've added the call in question

Comment: @Emeritus did you find a solution/workarround for this problem. I see the same problem in my post requests after migration to Angular 15